# Objective C to Swift bridge leads to heavy CPU usage when converting arrays in Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3

Having upgraded to Swift 3 my OSX app has started eating up the CPU when dealing with relatively big arrays (500+ custom objects) being passed form the Objective C layer to the Swift layer.

The array exists in an Objective C class

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *readings;
```

And is called in a Swift class

```
let readings = self.observation.readings
```

From the Instruments developer tool results it looks like the problem is happening at the `unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC` call

```
Weight      Self    Weight   Symbol Name
208.00 ms   95.8%   0 s      static Array._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(NSArray?) -> [A]
```

I have tried removing the line that makes this call and the problem goes away. I don't see this problem is Swift 2. The conversion is fine for smaller arrays and increases in CPU usage uniformly as the array grows.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way of avoiding this conversion and still being able to access elements in the array without touching the Objective C code? The array is rebuilt every time there is a call so I can't just manage it on the Swift side.

Comment: What happens to the performance if you declare `readings` to be `NSArray` like this: `let readings: NSArray = self.observations.readings`

Comment: Can't implicitly cast from `[Any]`. When I do an explicit cast CPU usage is still as high. You are on the right lines though. When I add an ObjC extension which exposes an `objectAtIndex` method avoiding the cast it works. Definitely not the ideal solution though.